# How do I shorten repeating code in c# windows form?

Tags: c#, windows, forms

So I'm trying to find a way of creating a code "shortcut" in C# windows form.

For example: during my whole code I'll need to repeat a specific lines of code over and over, and since it can be as easy as just doing copy and paste it can be easier if I could make my own shortcut.

Ex:

```
Void test
{
if (x > 1)
{
sw.WriteLine("X > 1!");
}
}
```

So later in the code I just need to write

```
test;
```

in order to do the whole code I set in the void function.

However in c# windows form "Void" function doesn't work as intended.

How do I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Where is x and sw declared.

Comment: That's not a *shortcut*. It's a function. You should find a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

If you repeat code then you have to create a method something like this

```
public static void test(int x)
{
   if (x > 1)
   {
     Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

then you can call that method anywhere in your code like below

```
test(5); // it print 5 to console
test(-2); // it don't print anythng
```